# MouseClick event on JSpinner component is not working

Tags: java, event-handling

I am trying to get a message to show when either buttons of a JSpinner is clicked or a value is typed into it. The problem is the event does not fire at all and i don't know why. The JSpinner is a member of a JPanel Form which can be added to a JFrame. The following is my code:

```
public class PropertyEditor extends javax.swing.JPanel {


public PropertyEditor() {
    initComponents();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jSpinner1 = new javax.swing.JSpinner();

    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(151, 200));

    jSpinner1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jSpinner1MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(19, 19, 19)
            .addComponent(jSpinner1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 105, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(27, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jSpinner1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(269, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jSpinner1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
    javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "wow");
}                                      


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JSpinner jSpinner1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Don't add mouse listeners to a JSpinner. Use a ChangeListener instad, either to the JSpinner or its model.

Answer (score -1):

2nd Edit:

`jSpinner1.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() { @Override public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent changeEvent) { javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "wow"); } });`

Use this `ChangeListener`. I have tried everything myself. This is the only listener, which, in my case, works with the spinner.